# Date.today not corresponding to the actual date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, clockwork

I noticed a very strange issue in my logs with regards to the current time when using `Date.today` method. Basically, I have a cron job (using clockwork) that runs every night at 00:00, to check which subscriptions are due, so that it tries to automatically renew them. The job executes a method which in turn executes a query, as follows:

```
where("date(active_until) <= ?", Date.today)
```

Most times this executes correctly. However, from my log observations, it seems that there are times when `Date.today` does not correspond to the actual date. Pulled from my logs:

Note: The dates are in the future because I was manually setting the time to test whether this executes correctly.

```
D, [2016-05-01T00:00:00.015901 #21699] DEBUG -- :   Subscription Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE date(active_until) <= '2016-04-30'

D, [2016-05-02T00:00:00.011130 #21721] DEBUG -- :   Subscription Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE date(active_until) <= '2016-05-02'
```

If you look at the first case, you will see that the statement was executed at `2016-05-01T00:00:00.015901`, while Date.today produced `2016-04-30`. The second case is obviously correct since the log date corresponds to the Date.today.

The biggest issue is that I am not able to reproduce it. The only thing I see from my logs is that it has happened 3 out of 24 times. What could be the issues here? Is it possible that Rails is somehow caching the input parameters to the query?

My Ruby version is: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

My Rails version is: 4.2.1

Comment: Have you tried `Time.zone.today`? It looks like a timezone issue to me.

Comment: If indeed its a timezone issue, that why we don't see this behaviour consistently?

Comment: Well, if your timezone's offset is -5 (from UTC) you will be fine as long as you are between: Midnight and 7PM, because Today will match.

Comment: @Leito for readability purposes [`Date.current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Date.html#method-c-current) performs this for you with a check to see if `Time.zone` or `config.time_zone` are set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `config/application.rb` file that your timee zone is set to the actual time zone you are testing in:

For PST we use:

`config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'`

To get a list of timezone strings useable by rails run this command:

`rake time:zones:all`

You can also give it a more specific locale. For USA:

`rake time:zones:us`

Comment: The timezone is set correctly, and as I said in a previous comment, if this was a timezone issue, the behaviour would be consistent (meaning that each time at midnight we would see a mismatch). In this case, out of 23 times, 4 times we see a mismatch in dates at the EXACT same time.

Comment: Ok. You might try using `<= Date.today.end_of_day`.  If you are using something like `1.month.from_now` to set the end of subscription it is exactly to the hour 1 month from now.

Answer (score -1):

As this happens around midnight I believe it is a timing issue where the log file is updated slightly after the script that generates the entry has been executed.
Might be load related as the logging facility is separate from the script sending the log entry.